# C# spaces in path

Tags: c#, path

I've seen tens of questions and answers concerning this subject but I still couldn't solve my problem.

I'm using an external ffmpeg converter in my code and I'm passing a file path as an argument like this:

```
OutputPackage oo = converter.ConvertToFLV(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\test Video\video.wmv");
```

When there is no space in "test Video" folder name ,then it works fine. But when it's like above I get an error that `C:\Users\user\Documents\test` is not a valid path.

Surrounding it with quotes like:

```
@"""C:\Users\user\Documents\test Video\video.wmv"""
```

results with

> The video file "C:\Users\user\Documents\test Video\video.wmv" does not exist.

I also tried without the "@":

```
"\"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test Video\\video.wmv\""
```

but the result is the same.

```
Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test Video\\video.wmv")
"\""+Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test Video\\video.wmv")+"\""
```

also doesn't work.
In the same time running the process form Windows Console like

```
ffmpeg.exe "C:\Users\user\Documents\test Video\video.wmv"
```

works totally fine.

UPDATE:
The method uses the string like this:

```
public OutputPackage ConvertToFLV(string inputPath)
{
    VideoFile vf = null;
    try
    {
        //string path = string.Format("{0}", inputPath);
        vf = new VideoFile(inputPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    OutputPackage oo = ConvertToFLV(vf);
    return oo;
}
```

and

In the video file class the exception is thrown here:

```
if (!File.Exists(_Path))
{
    throw new Exception("The video file " + _Path + " does not exist.");
}
```

Comment: Try forward slashes. `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: Try forward slash??  c:/dir/file

Comment: The `@""` string literal notation is a compiler thing. It doesn't matter if you use it or escape every sincle instance of `\`, the resulting string is the same. In any case, this smells like a bug in the library you're using.

Comment: A problem could be in the ConvertToFLV methond too. Can you post the code ot hat method?

Comment: Are you trying to look into another user's files perhaps?

Comment: the forward slashes don't work too, I even tried C:\test Video\vide.wmv, and it throws the same exception on the File.Exists(...)

Answer (score 4):

It could be that `converter.ConvertToFLV` doesn't handle path names with spaces in them correctly. You can try giving it the [8.3 pathname](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/crajesh1981/RajeshPage103142006044841AM/RajeshPage1.aspx) which doesn't have spaces

Comment: It looks that the File.Exists method doesn't work with all these strings. When I deleted the checking everything goes fine (however I think that not checking wether the file exists or not on applicaton level is not a proper way of overcoming this problem)

Comment: @Matt: You should post this as answer to make it useful for others who might run into the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to wrap the subject...

While outside tasks like ffmpeg require the paths containing spaces to be put in qoutes "path"(because Windows console sees a space as a delimiter between parameters), the method File.Exists() used in C# doesn't accept quotes in paths, and works good with spaces in paths.